# Mysql Index is not using

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows:

desc log;

```
+-------------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field             | Type                          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-------------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| time              | timestamp                     | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| severity          | enum('0','1','2','3','4','5') | NO   |     | 1                 |       |
| user_id           | bigint(20)                    | YES  | MUL | NULL              |       |
| user_ip           | varchar(15)                   | YES  | MUL | NULL              |       |
| module            | varchar(30)                   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| message           | text                          | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| blog_id           | bigint(20)                    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| event_type        | varchar(255)                  | YES  | MUL | NULL              |       |
| post_id           | bigint(20)                    | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| data              | longtext                      | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| data_integer      | tinyint(4)                    | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| data_integer_type | varchar(100)                  | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+-------------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

The table has following indexes:

```
show indexes from log;
+-------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| log |          1 | log_event_type_idx |            1 | event_type  | A         |          30 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| log |          1 | log_user_id_idx    |            1 | user_id     | A         |       10938 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| log |          1 | log_blog_id_idx    |            1 | blog_id     | A         |       24064 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| log |          1 | log_user_ip_idx    |            1 | user_ip     | A         |       24064 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| log |          1 | log_time_idx       |            1 | time        | A         |      240647 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

When I am querying data for Aug or Sep, it uses the index and works fine. But for Oct data, it does not use index. In the table maximum date is '2012-10-15'.
I added the explain plans.

```
explain
select *
from log
where time >= '2012-08-01 00:00:00'  AND time < '2012-09-01 00:00:00'

+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | log | range | log_time_idx | log_time_idx | 4       | NULL | 57306 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

explain
select *
from log
where time >= '2012-09-01 00:00:00'  AND time < '2012-10-01 00:00:00'

+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | log | range | log_time_idx | log_time_idx | 4       | NULL | 42569 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+

explain
select *
from log
where time >= '2012-10-01 00:00:00'  AND time < '2012-11-01 00:00:00'

+----+-------------+-------------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys        | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | log | ALL  | log_time_idx | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 481300 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Do you have any idea what the problem is? I am using Mysql 5.1.48.

Comment: do you have any value between those days?

Comment: Yes. I have. May be 299011 records.

Comment: I'd try `OPTIMIZE TABLE` or `ANALYZE TABLE` to make sure index stats are up to date. It can be lengthy operation , so check documentation before doing so (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html)

Comment: I used those commands, but still the same. I have no clue.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670810/mysql-explain-type-changes-from-range-to-ref-when-the-date-in-the-where-st

Comment: I found that the index use if the date range is small like '2012-10-01' to '2012-10-03' and same for others. Is there any reason that the number of data effecting this index usage?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL seemingly hates ranges with high cardinality.  This shows itself very quickly when working with `DATETIME` values.

You can reduce the cardinality by adding a `DATE` column to the table for the queries.  The cardinality will be much lower, and MySQL will be more likely to use the index.