# mysql sql plan ,what type=range meaning in this sql

Tags: mysql, indexing, range, explain

```
explain SELECT * FROM pop_order_info poi  WHERE poi.is_delete = 0  and poi.vendor_id =7879  group by poi.order_sn limit 10;        
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                      | key                          | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+

|  1 | SIMPLE      | poi   | range | vendor_id_2,is_delete_vendor_id_order_sn,vendor_id | is_delete_vendor_id_order_sn | 5       | NULL | 158462 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The above query is very slow!
I created an index: `is_delete_vendor_id_order_sn(is_delete,vendor_id,order_sn)`.

What does the 'type=range' mean in the above explain output?

Very fast by add hint:

```
explain SELECT * FROM pop_order_info poi use index(is_delete_vendor_id_order_sn) WHERE poi.is_delete = 0  and poi.vendor_id =7879  group by poi.order_sn limit 10;      
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                | key                          | key_len | ref         | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+

|  1 | SIMPLE      | poi   | ref  | is_delete_vendor_id_order_sn | is_delete_vendor_id_order_sn | 5       | const,const | 158462 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks for formating the code.

Comment: What version?  I reproduced something similar in 5.6.12.

Answer (score 3):

The `type` column of `EXPLAIN` output describes how tables are joined.

> ***The following list describes the join types, ordered from the best***
>   **type to the worst**:
>
> - system
> - const
> - eq_ref
>
> > - **ref**
> >
> > > All rows with matching index values are read from this table for each
> > >       combination of rows from the previous tables. ref is used if the join
> > >       uses only a leftmost prefix of the key or if the key is not a `PRIMARY`
> > >       `KEY` or `UNIQUE` index (in other words, if the join cannot select a
> > >       single row based on the key value). If the key that is used matches
> > >       only a few rows, this is a good join type.
>
> - fulltext
> - ref_or_null
> - index_merge
> - unique_subquery
> - index_subquery
>
> > - **range**
> >
> > > Only rows that are in a given range are retrieved, using an index to
> > >       select the rows. The key column in the output row indicates which
> > >       index is used. The key_len contains the longest key part that was
> > >       used. The ref column is `NULL` for this type.
> > >
> > > range can be used when a key column is compared to a constant using
> > >       any of the `=, <>, >, >=, <, <=, IS NULL, <=>, BETWEEN, or IN()`
> > >       operators:

If you are wonsering why `join type` , when retrieving from single table ,Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670810/mysql-explain-type-changes-from-range-to-ref-when-the-date-in-the-where-st)

Read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types) on `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: I known the ordinary 'range' type operation.But in this SQL,I have two equal conditions,should be 'ref' (when I use hint,the execution plan ok)

Answer (score 1):

There have been several bug fixes in this area in 5.6 and 5.7.  Consider upgrading.  However there are still open bugs in the general area.

A recent, not yet fixed, bug is [optimizer prefers using index `a` to ORDER instead of `b,a` to EQ and ORDER](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78997).

You may want to create another bug with your case.